# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables using array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add some fields to a table but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\GuildSite\Include\Database.php on line 69
```

This is the function I have to insert into a table:
I did move the $stmt === false before the foreach loop

```
public function myinsert($sqlInsert,$param)
{
$stmt = $this->_connection->prepare($sqlInsert) ;
if ($stmt === FALSE) 
{
  die($this->_connection->error);
}
echo 'Parameters number: ' . sizeof($param) ;
foreach ( $param as $key => $field )
{
  $stmt->bind_param ( $key , $field ) ;
}

$result = $stmt->execute() ;
$stmt->close();
return $result ;
}
```

From the page with the form, I have these parameters and this is how I call the function:

```
$param[':name'] =$_POST["personaName"];
$param[':email'] = $_POST["email"];
$param[':pass'] = $_POST['password'] ;
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `new_member`(`persona_name`, `email`, `password`) "
      . "VALUES (':name', ':email', ':pass');";
$db->myinsert($sqlInsert , $param) ;
```

There was a small error in the $sqlInsert no ' around the values. This is sorted

What am I doing wrong?

I did copy the sql insert from the phpMyadmin after inserting a new row in the table.

I did try to run the execute

```
$result = $stmt->execute($param) ;
```

but it still wouldn't insert any fields in the table.

this is my database connection

```
public function __construct()
{
  try
  {
    $this->_connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) ;
  } 
  catch (Exception $e) 
  { 
    echo $e->errorMessage(); 
  }
}
```

When I did check the size of the array I got a size of 3

Comment: Are you sure that $sqlInsert is valid SQL?

Comment: The way you've created your array, you should be able to just use `$result = $stmt->execute($param);`.

Comment: Did you call `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` on your connection?. This should cause it to raise an exception if the prepare failed

Comment: Also, you should move the `stmt === FALSE` test block before the foreach block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the wrong arguments to [bind_param()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). You must specify a string to indicate parameter types as a first argument. So you might retrieve the data type initials, as required by `bind_param()`, at runtime, like that:

```
$types = '';
foreach ( $param as $key => $field )
{
  $types .= gettype($field)[0];
}
```

Now that can be used as a first argument to your `bind_param()`.
Also, looking at the documentation alone, the function doesn't seem to allow named parameters, only indexed ones.
So, it seems like very difficult to continue using `bind_param()` to execute your query.
The function doesn't lend itself well to your use case.
You might use the PDO mysql interface and [PDO::bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead which supports named parameters.